# prove that composition of 2 functions is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Given that:
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases}a \qquad x \ge 2 \\
> b \qquad x <2
> \end{cases}$$
>   $$g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-2x}$$
>   and $-1<a<0<b<1$
>
> prove that $f$ and $g$ are not differentiable at $x=2$ and that $g(f(x))$ is not differentiable at $x=2$.

Please let me know if my logic is correct. Since $a \neq b$ the one-sided limits of $f(x)$ are not equal therefore $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=2$ thus $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=2$.

If we try to calculate the limit of $g(x)$ at $x=2$ we get $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{1}{x^2-2x}$. We can see that $g(x)$ is not defined at $x=2$ and again one-sided limits are unequal: $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. Thus $g(x)$ is not continuous and thus not differentiable.

Regarding $g(f(x))$:
$$g(f(x)) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{a^2-2a} \qquad x \ge 2 \\
\frac{1}{b^2-2b} \qquad x <2
\end{cases}$$
It is given that $-1<a<0$ and also that $0<b<1$ so $0<-2a<2$ and $-2<-2b<0$. Immediately we can see that $\frac{1}{a^2-2a}>0$. It is worth noting that squaring a rational number ($a$ and $b$ are not integers) will result either in a smaller number or equal therefore $b^2<b<2b \Rightarrow \frac{1}{b^2-2b}<0$. Therefore $\frac{1}{a^2-2a} \neq \frac{1}{b^2-2b}$ Therefore one-sided limits of $g(f(x))$ at $x=2$ are unequal $\Rightarrow g(f(x))$ is not continuous at $x=2 \Rightarrow g(f(x))$ is not differentiable at $x=2$.

Comment: Unless you've made a mistake, $g$ is perfectly well-defined and differentiable at $x=2$. Should it be $\dfrac{1}{x^2-4}$?

Comment: sorry, made a mistake

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta based on OP's formulation for $g(f(x))$ I'm guessing that $g(x)$ should be $\dfrac{1}{x^2-2x}$.

Comment: But you cannot suppose that $a=-1$ nor $b=3$ as it's out of given range

Comment: So $f(x), g(x),$ and $g\circ f(x)$ are all discontinuous at 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fix:

> It is worth noting that squaring a rational number ($a$ and $b$ are not integers) will result either in a smaller number or equal

This is not true. For example, $3/2$ is rational but $\left(\frac32\right)^2 \not< \frac32$.

It *is* true that $b^2 < b < 2b$, but the reason is because $0 < b < 1$.  We don't know that $b$ is rational, and this is not a property of rational numbers anyway.

Comment: You're right, but I meant rational in the sense that it's a fraction. I guess this what I should've said

Comment: So could I say that squaring a fraction given that the nominator is less than denominator will result in a smaller or equal number?

Comment: @Yos, no, don't say that either.  Fraction sort of implies rational, but more importantly, fraction most certainly doesn't imply "between $0$ and $1$."  For example, $3/2$ is a fraction.  Even if you qualify the numerator should be smaller, you're excluding irrationals.  For example, $0 < \pi - 3 < 1$, but how do you express $\pi-3$ as a fraction?  It's safest to say "$b^2 < b < 2b$ because $0 < b < 1$."

Comment: Ok, but regarding my solution overall is it correct?

Comment: @Yos, yes, nevermind, otherwise looks fine.